# Where do I put a post-commit hook script?

Tags: linux, svn, bash, post-commit

I've just thrown together the following shell script:

```
cd /home/firefli/webprojects/project1
svn checkout file:///home/firefli/svn/project1/trunk .
rm -rf /home/firefli/public_html/project1
svn export . /home/firefli/public_html/project1
```

It does work when I do a commit and then run the script manually but I still have a couple of questions.

**Can I run a bash script, or does it have to be C? (I've seen lots of C examples)**

**Where do I put it to make it execute post-commit?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `hooks` directory inside your Subversion repository. It should contain a number of templates that you can modify and use.

Your script can happily be a bash script. The provided templates use `/bin/sh`

Just remove the `.tmpl` extension and you're good to go.

The Subversion docs provide more info [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks)